# how to read a specific file name and file type extension in a folder and each subfolder using powershell? Newbie in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$files = Get-ChildItem "$logfiles" -Filter *.csv



for ($i=0; $i g-t $files.Count; $i++) {
        Get-Content $files[$i].FullName | Where-Object { ($_ -match 'honey[5]' ) }
```

Here's my code. I want to read the data of csv file names "honey". And show it in the console

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: what does your csv look like, and what are you wanting the output to be?

Comment: If these are Csvs you should start by treating them as structured data, use `Import-Csv` to read them to produce objects out of them instead of plain strings

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem ".\logs" -Recurse -Filter *honey*.csv

for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) { Get-Content $files[$i] }
```

You can do your filtering for specific file names in your `Get-ChildItem` command.

You had a typo in your for loop.  The `g-t` should have been `-lt`.

Since we're now filtering by file name in `Get-ChildItem` we can drop the `Where-Object` in the loop.

The `-Recurse` parameter in the `Get-ChildItem` will search sub-directories under the parent folder.

This should successfully display the contents of files with "honey" in the file name.

Comment: hi, Thanks for your answer! But All I want is to  filter a file type extension in a folder with subfolder? Example folder has its own subfolder containing .csv file type and has different file name but the same file type. All I wanted to do is , I want my script to read each .csv file in every folder and subfolder and convert all read csv into .txt. I am newbie in powershell

Comment: I try this but I have error :
$files = Get-ChildItem "$logfiles\" -Recurse -Filter *.csv                                                      
  for ($i=0; $i -lt $files.Count; $i++) { Get-Content $files[$i] }

Comment: error message:                                                                                                                       
+                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\c.amoguiz\SQL_boe21.csv:String) [Get-Content], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand

Comment: Are you wanting to just rename the *.csv files to *.txt files or are you wanting to change the contents of the files?  Can you please edit your question to provide an example input and output?